# Looking for an up-to-date GUI/Launcher/Autorun creating software

Tags: windows, gui, launcher, gui-builder

For the longest time, I've been using Autoplay Media Studio to create simple launchers. However, it hasn't been updated in s long time and the resulted launcher isn't really portable (folder with resources + 2 dlls must be present). So, essentially, I'm looking for an up-to-date, (preferably) free/cheaper alternative to AMS. The program should have the following features:

1. Visual GUI editor
2. Be able to do common tasks (Launch a program,read/write registry, copy/move/delete files/folder, play common media formats, etc.)
3. Not rely on external programs to use the created GUI (i.e. I'm not looking for Qt Designer)
4. (Preferably) use a scripting language for task automation
5. Create a fast-loading portable executable
6. Create frameless windows of any size.

Is there any such software available out there, that's still under active development? I've tried Googling, but the only results I got were outdated Autorun Software (such as AMS), and simple GUI designers, that let you design a GUI, however they don't contain a compiler and leave it to you figure out what to do with the resulted GUI.

Comment: For what OS? Android?

Comment: Also, please describe exactly what you call a "launcher", thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul added "Windows" tag. By "launcher" I mean a small GUI program, whose purpose is to run other software, such as autorun programs used in old CD releases to "launch" the installer. A launcher can be used for various tasks, such as replacing several windows shortcuts, or to create quick GUIs for command-line based programs.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily accomplished using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and creating an executable via the [Ahk2Exe](https://github.com/fincs/Ahk2Exe) utility or similarly using [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

Both of them have many functions that will allow you to create a GUI, read/write registry records etc.

Sadly, as far as I know, none of them have a built-in GUI Editor so you will either have to create it by hand, which is not as difficult as it sounds.

You may use a third party tool such as [AutoGUI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/autogui/) for AutoHotkey which seems to be working as both an editor and GUI creator.

Sadly I can't provide as much information for AutoIT as I am not as familiar with it as with AHK.

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of AutoGUI. I'll give this a try.

Comment: The preview window is glitching, although the output exe looks exactly as it should. Offers very little visual editing, preview is mainly useful for positioning and only if turn on the borders, since you can't see the actual object. The non-functional (semi-functional) preview window defeats the purpose.